# Left the previous job because of family issue

Tags: interviewing, personal-problems

I am Taiwanese, I've stayed and worked about 10 years in the US, 
and decided to comeback my country this summer.

Frankly, the reason I decided to come back to Taiwan is that I wasn't happy with my life in the US and I missed my family. Moreover my dad underwent a huge operation, and I made a quick decision to come back home to stay with him.  Luckily, he got well.

I started to look for a job in Asia.  Since I want to keep my international work experiences and staying in Asia makes me feel relieved. (Stay close to my family)

I'm scheduled for a job interview with a company in China (Mainland),

If they asked me:

> Why did you move back to your country /leave the US?

Should I answer them the reason honestly?  I'm afraid that the hiring manager might think that I am emotionally weak or can't handle personal matters and my personal matters affect my work life.

Comment: In your case, you left for all the right reason.  The truth will set you free.

Answer (score 14):

Honestly I'm glad you're a person that cares about your parents. Regarding to your question, I'd answer:

> My main reason to come home was to take care of my parents, because my dad had to get a huge surgery. They used to take care of me, and now I could give them something in return. Also, after spending so much time abroad I can now give my experience and knowledge back to China.

In my opinion you'll look like a person with a remarkable character and strong convictions. Isn't family life very important in China? The company will probably understand.

Answer (score 7):

In your case the truth is a perfectly reasonable explanation, so use it, you have no need for subterfuge.

Comment: And would you really want to work for a company that had a problem with you coming home to deal with a family emergency? So if they don't pick you only because of this, I'd say you dodged a bullet.